# ERROR Could not build wheels for xmlsec, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, xmlsec

I am having an error when trying to install Rasa X in local mode form Terminal. Using Python 3.7.4 and pip version 21.3.1. Using Mac.

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec
  Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  Complete output (14 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'src/xmlsec/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/tree.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/constants.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/template.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
  running build_ext
  error: Unable to invoke pkg-config.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: same, they ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this before installing Rasa X:
`brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1 pkg-config`

Comment: Should this be done in the 'venv' where Rasa version is installed? (it is a different version from that outside the venv). Thanks

Comment: This solved the issue for me!

Comment: @uk_butterfly I believe `brew install` downloads packages for your Mac itself, so the command above can be run anywhere and this should work.